# "positive matrices" in Sylvester's criterion

Tags: linear-algebra

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion):

> Sylvester's criterion states that a Hermitian matrix ''M'' is positive-definite if and only if all the following matrices have a positive determinant:
>
> - the upper left 1-by-1 corner of $M$,
> - the upper left 2-by-2 corner of $M$,
> - the upper left 3-by-3 corner of $M$,
> - ...
> - $M$ itself.
>
> In other words, all of the leading principal minors must be positive.

So do we call a principal minor positive if it has a positive determinant? Because from my knowledge a *positive matrix* is just a matrix with *positive elements.* In this sense the positive definite hermitian (symmetric) matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

would have principal minors which are not positive matrices.

Comment: The word *minor* usually refers to a sub*determinant* (not a sub*matrix*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the usage of this context, the $m \times m$ upper-left corner of a matrix is referred to as the *leading principal **submatrix***.

The *determinant* of this matrix is referred to as the $m$th leading principal minor.

Answer (score 0):

**Positive-definite** is not **positive elements**. It means that for every vector $x\not=0$: $$x^TAx\geq0.$$
So, yes, this hermitian matrix is possitive.

Comment: Your notations seem off. Do you mean that $x^T A x \geq 0$?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the correction.

Comment: In some books, a positive matrix is defined as a matrix with positive entries. So it is best to always check the definition.